# Invisible Character Unicode

Tags: php, unicode, integer, alt

Does anyone know if there is any invisible character other than the space? like a website using (Example: This [Invisible Character](https://invisiblecharacter.net)). Is it possible to programmatically add some such characters that are not shown by any editor, i'm trying by unicode but when ever i paste it so it takes same unicode but don't copy it as an invisible character?

Comment: PHP or *any* editor? In any case no. You have a file with is a Unicode string. Copying is just taking a part of it, without mangling. Note: some operating system may later re-encode that string, and so removing bad files. But "any" editor is too generic. And because a well known "vulnerability", most editor will show invisible characters anyway, for safety reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other invisible characters. Like for example U+200b.
This might be even invisible in your Code Editor.

For example VSCode however [has a feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1kyIUZgzqo) now to highlight invisible unicode characters.

To type a chracter like this on windows for example:

> To insert a Unicode character, type the character code, press ALT, and then press X. For example, to type a dollar symbol ($), type 0024, press ALT, and then press X. For more Unicode character codes, see Unicode character code charts by script.

Source: [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0)

The Website you linked used a character that's invisible but adds some "whitespace". The character I choose as an example is invisible but doesn't cause visible space between other characters.

[This Website](https://invisible-characters.com) offers a list of many different types of invisible Unicode characters for reference.